# Connect to third-party api through gateway or service in microservice

Tags: microservices

I'm developing a microservice using nestjs and am planning to connect to third-party API, but where should I put the connection? Service controller or gateway controller?

Comment: You can use a gateway to make the connection to the third party api. Hope this helps!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.